# Convert HTML String to byte array java

Tags: java, html, arrays

I want to convert an HTML string to a byte array so when I get the byte array it is in HTML format. I converting plain HTML string to byte array but when I retrieve it, it's just plain text of HTML but I want it to be formatted in HTML.

```
final String html = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n" +
                "<html>\n" +
                "<head>\n" +
                "<style>\n" +
                "table {\n" +
                "  font-family: arial, sans-serif;\n" +
                "  border-collapse: collapse;\n" +
                "  width: 100%;\n" +
                "}\n" +
                "\n" +
                "td, th {\n" +
                "  border: 1px solid #dddddd;\n" +
                "  text-align: left;\n" +
                "  padding: 8px;\n" +
                "}\n" +
                "\n" +
                "tr:nth-child(even) {\n" +
                "  background-color: #dddddd;\n" +
                "}\n" +
                "</style>\n" +
                "</head>\n" +
                "<body>\n" +
                "\n" +
                "<h2>HTML Table</h2>\n" +
                "\n" +
                "<table>\n" +
                "  <tr>\n" +
                "    <th>Company</th>\n" +
                "    <th>Contact</th>\n" +
                "    <th>Country</th>\n" +
                "  </tr>\n" +
                "  <tr>\n" +
                "    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>\n" +
                "    <td>Maria Anders</td>\n" +
                "    <td>Germany</td>\n" +
                "  </tr>\n" +
                "</table>\n" +
                "\n" +
                "</body>\n" +
                "</html>\n";
        Spanned d  = Html.fromHtml(html);
```

I converted the plaintext to HTML using fromHTML() but then I'm unable to convert spanned to byte array. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you simply want `html.getBytes(StandardCharSets.UTF_8)` or something else? If so, exactly what do you want?

Comment: If you save html code into a byte array as String, you will get output as String inevitably because String is what you are storing into it. Once you extract the entire code String, you can save it in a file with .html output. Then you will have a HTML file. Because Java's byte array cannot identify if the String you are storing is html or css or js or anyother. It will be just String.

Comment: @The_Humble_Fool So, you mean if I store my HTML in a .html file and then convert it to byte array I would be able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Add a dependency to JSOUP to your pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you can pretty print your HTML string using the `parse` method of the `Jsoup` utility class:

```
System.out.println(Jsoup.parse(html).toString());
```